# Anyone use xui? JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, xui

Warning: Java newbie.

Been looking at [XUI](http://www.xoetrope.com/xui) for Java. Its looks quite interesting. Sort of liek a WPF way of designing interfaces. But googling around I don't see much other than articles saying it had been released. So is it used much or a bit niche?

Are there other similar frameworks for Java? Was looking at JavaFX but seems to be a general feeling that it has been slow development wise. Are there other frameworks that work in simialr ways? I get the impression Swing/SWT seem to more like WinForms. I'm looking to do something a bit more WPF like. As I said, Java newbie, so I might have this all confused. Seem to be so many UI frameworks its a bit overwhelming working out what to use for a new project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use JavaFx, Take a look http://www.swixml.org.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFx is a nice framework, it is pretty easy to learn and use. There are also some nice tutorials, doco, API's available, its still only in Preview SDK at the moment, but the next reelase is expected out relativly soon.

I would recommend giving it a try

[official javaFx site](http://javafx.com/)

[suns JavaFX overview](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/)

[openjfx](https://openjfx.dev.java.net/)